# Azure account trial creating some problems?

Tags: azure

I am using azure trial hosting for a month or so.
But now I don't have any website hosted on that.
So how can i close the trial period of that service from azure.
At the moment I don't have any website to host. So please anyone can tell me how to close this account.

Thanks

Jatin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to Azure Management portal, click on account settings (it will be displayed as your login id), then click on view my bill or login to (https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions). Now click on the subscription and see for the option "Cancel Subscription".